# ionic app showing blank after renaming package name

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3, slim

Please I need help. I develop an ionic 3 app and it was running well, I did not remember to renaming the package name during setup. I then decided to rename the package name and when I serve the app it runs perfectly on browser. I then try to emulate it, it shows white screen after splash screen. I remove the platform and then delete all the plugins and then reinstall all the plugins and add the platform still no luck. 
Any ideas please, I will appreciate. Also I check using google inspect from the emulator and there seems to be no error.

Comment: have you tried removind node_modules and run npm install?

Comment: Try deleting the app from the emulator and restarting your emulation

Comment: @GabrielBarreto I have done that several times and still no luck. I have deleted the app from my emulator and restart and test same issue. I deleted it from my android device and install it and same issue.